# How to bulk_create in django using MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, bulkinsert

Does not return ID when using bulk_create method. PostgreSQL returns the ID, but MySQL does not.
Is there a way to create a temporary ID and solve it?

```
bar_list = []
foo_list = []
for i in range(3):
    foo = Foo(body="text")
    foo.temp_id = uuid.uuid4()
    foo_list.append(foo)

    bar = Bar(foo_temp_id=foo.temp_id, body="text")
    bar_list.append(bar)

Foo.objects.bulk_create(foo_list)  # The query sets are created, but the ID is None
Bar.objects.bulk_create(bar_list)  # Error occurred because the ID of the referring foo is None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the documented limitations of django ORM's [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method if the id field is AutoField:

> If the model’s primary key is an AutoField, the primary key attribute can only be retrieved on certain databases (currently **PostgreSQL, MariaDB 10.5+, and SQLite 3.35+**). On other databases, it will not be set.

You either have to provide the id explicitly when you create the Foo objects or you cannot use bulk_create with mysql in this instance.

Comment: That's what I already knew. Is there any other way?

Comment: Not that I can think of.